# Enterprise Architect - SysML Diagram Heading

Tags: enterprise-architect, sysml

I hope this is an easy question - how do I get the SysML Diagram Header to display the correct model element type (the information in the first set of square brackets)? My diagrams all display as [package].

I'm using Sparx Enterprise Architect Version 13.5.

Thanks

Comment: You should edit your question to share the code you are trying to use

Comment: Or just add a screen shot of the relevant part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "correct model element type" is the type of the model element containing the diagram.  The Diagram Frame represents the model element in which the diagram is contained and therefore the model element type is frequently, for many BDDs, the name of the package containing the diagram.  Suggest reading OMG SysML specification v1.5 Annex A: Diagrams for details.  It is free.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I understand the elements of the diagram frame and was looking for help on how to achieve that in EA.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. I have resolved this issue by stereotyping the parent element (package) in the project tree to the model element type I need. This results in the appropriate model element type information appearing in the diagram frame.